# Access can't represent the join expression joining on substring

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a complex query I'm trying to build in Access. I have used the Unmatched query wizard to check if several fields in one table don't match fields in another table. A couple of these need to be substrings. Basically If the right two characters of Table1.F = the right 2 characters of Table2.F.

My SQL is correct if I write it in SQL view. But when I try to switch back to design view, I get a message:

> Microsoft Access can't represent the join expression Right(Table1.F,2) = Right(Table2.F,2) in Design view.

This is essentially what I have:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON (TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A) AND (TABLE1.B = 
TABLE2.B)...
AND ( RIGHT(TABLE1.F,2) = RIGHT(TABLE2.F,2) )
SET TABLE1.ERROR = X
WHERE (TABLE2.A IS NULL) AND (TABLE2.B IS NULL)... ;
```

Is there a way to write this in a way that design view will accept?

Answer (score 0):

Respect  to mysql In ms-access the set values are placed before join condition

```
  UPDATE T 
  SET T.ERROR = X
  FROM TABLE1 AS T
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A 
        AND TABLE1.B = TABLE2.B ... 
           AND  RIGHT(TABLE1.F,2) = RIGHT(TABLE2.F,2)  
                AND TABLE2.A IS NULL AND TABLE2.B IS NULL ... ;
```

you can avoid unuseful  ( ) around comparision and  overall   don't use where condition on columns for table involved  in left join ..
 in this way the where work as an inner join
move the condition in  on clause for left join

Comment: It will not allow that. Syntax error. Does not like the "from" clause after the "set". The unnecessary parens are automatically added from the query builder. It loves them for some reason. I delete them and it puts them back.

Comment: answer  update  ..with alias for update  table  .. but sintactically seems correct  .. are yoiu sure you are using ms access  with this code ??

Answer (score 0):

i faced similar problem when i tried to format the SQL query with a online tool .it turns out that MS-access cant translate Joint part of the query if there are spaces just before or after brackets
for example

```
INNER JOIN Tb1 ON (Tb.F = Tb2.F1)
```

gets converted from Sql to Design view but

```
INNER JOIN Tb1 ON ( Tb.F = Tb2.F1 )
```

will not